# split by multiple \n and retaining same

Tags: python-3.x

I have string as given below . Which I want to split by  one or  more `\n` and maintain the occurrence of `\n` in resultant list .
Input string

```
str = "this is text document.\n\n which can be represented as below:\n\n\n"
```

output list

```
["this is text document.", "\n", "\n", "which can be represented as below:", "\n", "\n", "\n"]
```

How this can be done in pythonic way ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regex of an alternation pattern would be a fitting tool for the task:

```
import re

s = "this is text document.\n\n which can be represented as below:\n\n\n"
print(re.findall(r'\n|.+', s))
```

This outputs:

```
['this is text document.', '\n', '\n', ' which can be represented as below:', '\n', '\n', '\n']
```